# How can I fill out a jagged multi-dimensional array with undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

My goal is transpose a matrix; however, the sub-arrays do not all have equal length. For example: `[[1,2,3], [4,5], [0,-1,0,0]]`. I can't transpose this because the indices don't match up. What I need is:

```
[[1,2,3,undefined],
[4,5,undefined,undefined],
[0,-1,0,0]]
```

So that the shorter rows all match the same length as the longest row, but then are filled with `undefined` in the extended slots.

I'm well aware I can do this in ways that are probably considered slower or more crude, namely by initializing and empty array and copying, or concating arrays of `undefined`. Does javascript have some sort of native way of doing this? I took a look at [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), but it doesn't seem like what I need.

Comment: All arrays will have length 4?

Comment: Do you know the max length beforehand, or do you need to search the nested arrays for the max length first? Also, I'm not convinced `undefined` is the right thing to add.

Comment: @Andy Yeah, I need to determine the max length first. I don't know it in advance.

Comment: You are jumping from the notion of transposing a ragged array to needing to fill out the rows, There are ways of tranposing that would not require that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `length` property of array,

```
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [0,-1,0,0]];
//getting the max length among the sub arrays.
var max = arr.reduce(function(a,b){ return Math.max(a, b.length) }, 0);
//setting the max length to all the sub arrays.
arr = arr.map(function(itm){ return (itm.length = max, itm) });

console.log(arr[0]); //[1, 2, 3, undefined × 1]
console.log(arr[1]); //[4, 5, undefined × 2]
console.log(arr[2]); //[0, -1, 0, 0]
```

Ok here is a normal version of the above code,

```
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5],
  [0, -1, 0, 0]
];

//getting the max length among the sub arrays.
var max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return Math.max(a, b.length)
}, 0);

//setting the max length to all the sub arrays.
arr = arr.map(function(itm) {
  itm.length = max;
  return itm
});

console.log(arr[0]); //[1, 2, 3, undefined × 1]
console.log(arr[1]); //[4, 5, undefined × 2]
console.log(arr[2]); //[0, -1, 0, 0]
```

And here is a plain old for loop method for your clear understanding,

```
var arr = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5],[0, -1, 0, 0]];
var max = 0;

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
 max = Math.max(max, arr[i].length);
}
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
 arr[i].length = max
}

console.log(arr[0]); //[1, 2, 3, undefined × 1]
console.log(arr[1]); //[4, 5, undefined × 2]
console.log(arr[2]); //[0, -1, 0, 0]
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gop7fueu/2/)

Comment: Can you explain the syntax for `(itm.length = max, itm)`. What is going on here?

Comment: @AlanH That means `itm.length = max;  return itm;` It's a shorthand. I used comma operator there. It will be handy at situations like this.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand, can you write it out without shorthand?

Comment: @AlanH https://jsfiddle.net/gop7fueu/ Have a look at here. Also read about [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, it is bad style, because it has no functionality in this case. please have a look for some usfull cases [comma operator](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/)

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for the article.... I'm still confused by the use of `return` and `,` in this case.

Comment: @NinaScholz It can't be a bad style. Because.. Can you `arr = arr.map(function(itm) {
  itm.length = max;
  return itm;
});` use this code here? http://jscompress.com/ That will yield a result with comma separator. Thanks. :)

Comment: @AlanH It is a matter of choice alan, There is nothing evil in using a comma separator.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Could I trouble you by asking you to just write it out without the comma separator? I can't figure out what's going on there...

Comment: @AlanH For your clear understandin, I have written a code by using plain for loop. Seriously, that will be more efficient.

Comment: Your max calculation using `reduce` is just an awkward way of saying `Math.max(...arr.map(x => x.length))`.

Comment: @torazaburo Interesting way of using spread operator. But you are transforming the array unnecessarily there. Due to those complexity, I suggested OP using a simple for loop/

Answer (score 2):

`Array.reduce` function is a good stuff. But `Array.forEach` will go faster in this case. Besides, array `length` is dynamic property, no need to use `Array.map`:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [0,-1,0,0]],
    max = 0;

arr.forEach(function(v){ if (v.length > max) max = v.length; });
arr.forEach(function(v){ v.length = max; });
```

Comment: This is how I personally would do it.  The use of `reduce()` is clever but I think it overcomplicates this particular task.

Comment: @RickHitchcock, yes. We, developers, sometimes doing simple things in a complicated way )

Answer (score 1):

A version with `this`. Now with real `undefined`, not with sparse holes.

```js
var arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [0, -1, 0, 0]];

arr.forEach(function (item) {
    var i = item.length;
    while (i < this) {
        item[i++] = undefined;
    }
}, arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b.length);
}, 0));

arr[1].forEach(function (a, i) {
    document.write(i + ': ' + a + '<br>');
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Are you sure that this code will be readable for your peers in future? :) It is just a simple task for OP. Do not complicate it.

Comment: I have already +1 ed for you. Because you made me look at the doc today for forEach's second argument. :)

Comment: That's horrible. Gives entirely new meaning to the term "obfuscation". In addition, it doesn't even do what the OP claims to have wanted, which was to fill out the rows with "real" undefineds; whether or not that is actually necessary is another issue.

Comment: @torazaburo, there are real `undefined` in the array, please see edit. JSON.stringify displays them as `null`.

Comment: Wrong. JSON.stringify serializes holes in the array as null.

Comment: @torazaburo, `typeof` shows `'undefined'`. is that an error?

Comment: Well, we're talking about angels dancing on the head of a pin. The OP, for what it's worth, said ***filled* with undefined in the extended slots**. If I say `var a = [1]; a.length = 2;;`, then `a[1]` is not "filled with undefined"; it's a hole, which when I access it is reported as undefined, but is different.